# Free SVG editor better than Inkscape

Tags: gratis, svg

I know of the following SVG editors:

- BoxySVG
- Adobe Animate (formerly Flash Professional)
- Adobe Illustrator
- ToonBoom Studio

All paid. This is the only one I know that is free and open-source:

- Inkscape

However it's very inefficient for me. I think it has all needed functionality, but it's not intuitive to use and I waste time to do simple things. I'm very familiar to Adobe Animate.

Is there something better than Inkscape? For example, in Adobe Animate you can:

- Select an object and open a context with transform options, such as:

  - Rotation (free or exact (90 degrees and so on))
- Deform or manipulate shapes with the selection tool, for instance:

  - You can select a region of a shape and delete it with the <kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Check https://alternativeto.net/software/inkscape/?license=free, there are some free alternatives but you've try to judge

Comment: @RamiSedhom Vectornator is mobile-only. Krita, I've already tried it earlier and it's not similiar to Animate.

Answer (score 4):

**Is there something better than Inkscape?**

It depends what you mean by better. If your main issue with Inkscape is that "it's not intuitive to use and [you] waste time to do simple things", then there are tools that have fewer features, but are more intuitive to use.

Personally, "simple things" for me sounds like inserting simple shapes, images and text. If that's not what you mean by "simple things", please edit your question to add more specific requirements.

**Google Slides**

Weirdly, [Google Slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/)  can be used to create "simple" SVGs. It has the advantage to be free and no installation is needed.

Simply create your SVG and use the option: Download > SVG
[image]

For quick and simple things, that seems like a reasonable option with a relatively intuitive interface.

**PowerPoint**

Even though it's not free, I'm going to include this as well since you might already have it on your computer and/or it might be something you have access via a work or school subscription.

Just like Google Slides, PowerPoint can export your slides to SVG, it is an option to consider for simple SVGs production.

It even supports exporting all your slides as SVG natively unlike Google Slides which requires the use of a [script](https://gist.github.com/diverted247/4c32679519ce2d063934) that you paste in the developer console to export all selected slides.

Regarding the ease of use, PowerPoint has an intuitive and familiar interface, so if that's your main criteria, it has you covered.

Note that the online version of PowerPoint is free, but doesn't support exporting your slides to SVGs as far as I know.

Comment: Google Slides seems a little better than Inkscape, though I still find both inflexible. I think Inkscape is mature in terms of features, but it's not productive for simple and complex cases (including arts) and has an unintuitive UI. I can't say Adobe Animate was always good for me, but it was far better than Inkscape for any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape Release a new version 2 days ago, maybe some of their new features help you in your workflow...

https://inkscape.org/es/news/2023/07/23/inkscape-launches-version-13-focus-organizing-work/